# How do i convert an 8 bit binary data to hex

Tags: php, data-conversion

```
print_r(bin2hex("11111111"));
echo '</br>';
print_r(bindec("11111111"));
```

**Result**

- 131313131313131
- 255

> I want a hexadecimal 16 byte value to do aes encryption.How is the conversion from binary to hex happening in php.I am getting incorrect value using the function.Also when i convert an array of hexadecimal values to string the byte length changes

Comment: It would return 3131313131313131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a correct result, it's just not what you want. [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) returns an ASCII string of the hexadecimal representation. A quote from the manual:

> Returns an **ASCII string** containing the hexadecimal representation of str.

So If you want the hexadecimal number you can use this:

```
print_r(dechex(bindec("11111111")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The converter to get hexidecimal is `dechex()`, but it needs a decimal number. To do that we convert you binary string to a decimal number first using `bindec()` and then pass it into `dechex()`, e.g:

```
print_r(dechex(bindec("11111111")));
```

Comment: This gives me `313031303130303131303030313031303131303030313131` as output

Comment: Now you're writing something about `decbin()` in your text above your code and in your code you don't use it?!

Comment: @Rizier123 seriously, how about a little patience? It takes a few seconds to rewrite the code but a minute or so to rewrite the text.

Comment: I thought you forgot to change it and I though I notice you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world!";
echo bin2hex($str) . "<br>";
echo pack("H*",bin2hex($str)) . "<br>";
?>
```

**PHP.NET Manual :**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

**Test Your Result :** http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall07/cos109/bc.html

**Detailed Explanation:**
http://www.computerhope.com/binhex.htm

It's simply 9 * 16 + F where F is 15 (the letters A thru F stand for 10 thru 15). In other words, 0x9F is 159.

It's no different really to the number 314,159 being:

```
  3 * 100,000 (10^5, "to the power of", not "xor")
+ 1 *  10,000 (10^4)
+ 4 *   1,000 (10^3)
+ 1 *     100 (10^2)
+ 5 *      10 (10^1)
+ 9 *       1 (10^0)
for decimal (base 10).
```

The signedness of such a number is sort of "one level up" from there. The unsigned value of 159 (in 8 bits) is indeed a negative number but only if you interpret it as one.